# Accessing local groups remotly for a Windows Fileshare where user accounts are on an AD

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, file-sharing

I am asking this question with almost no knowledge of Windows and Active Directory.

I have a Windows Server (2012), that I am using as a file server (FILE01.domain.tld). There are some local groups that govern who gets access to which share. These users are in the ALPHA AD Domain.

Now, we have some desktop computers connected to the ALPHA domain, where users can login. What I would like to accomplish is if user ALPHA\colum logs into a desktop, the fileshares that the user has access to on the fileserver (the group FILE01.domain.tld\GROUP_ORG_FINANCE and the share FILE01.domain.tld\FINANCE) are mounted as network drives.

Now, I know I can try and mount each fileshare individually, but the issue here that if a new share is added down the road I have to go in and add it to the script on each computer. So, any ideas how to accomplish this? I am not opposed to running my own Active Directory, but if I did that, I would want the accounts to be the same on the AD I run and the ALPHA directory.

This is a foreign concept to me, so sorry if this is something really simple.

Answer (score 0):

Use the mapped network drive policy in group policy and preferences

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/01/07/using-group-policy-preferences-to-map-drives-based-on-group-membership.aspx

Comment: This won't be so easy as the OP is controlling access using local groups on the FS itself.

Comment: The local group will still manage access, and the policy can be applied selectively.

Comment: I assume that you're recommending to not use Item-Level Targetting then, but to have a separate policy just containing these drive maps?  I'm not sure that's a good thing to recommend.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. What's your reasoning?

Comment: Policies are far easier to manage if you use Item-Level Targetting, that's all.  As it stands you've a mixture of local groups, domain groups, and presumably an OU structure set up to apply domain policies to a specific subset of users - lots of places for things to wrong in, and not robust if you've got users who need access to two separate sets of drive maps.  Why not use a single domain group to manage both?

Comment: That makes sense, although I would probably use a hybrid approach. I would have a single policy for "Drive Mappings" that handles all mapping with item level targeting applied as necessary. Before all of that I would also explore using active directory groups to manage access